# Change the background color of dropdownlist JQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Below code doesn't seem to change the background color of dropdownlist. Please advice.

```
 var TextHighlightCss = {
        'background': '#FFFFAA',
        'border': '1px solid #FFAD33'
    };

 $('#ddlCarriers option:selected').css('TextHighlightCss');
```

Thanks in advance

BB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#ddlCarriers option:selected').css(TextHighlightCss);
```

You're passing a string, not your variable.

Comment: Thanks James. my bad. I knew css() works. But some times we need an extra set of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the apostrophes from the .css() part and it should work.

Also, you may like to see this:

http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/form_controls/select/

It shows the style differences between all browsers for select menus, quite handy.

Answer (score 0):

Please do it like this, if you can help it:

CSS:

```
.hightlight {
  background: #FFFFAA;
  border: 1px solid #FFAD33;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#ddlCarriers option:selected').addClass("hightlight");
```

Guy who needs to refactor it in the future:

(n/a)