# Conditional background/font color in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is this possible? I have the following in my cshtml (razor) MVC 4:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(v => v.Medico, ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Medicos), new { @class="span4"})
```

This is on controller, how I generate the list:

```
List<Medico> list = null;
Medico medico = null;
if (visitador != null){
    list = new List<Medico>(visitador.Medicos.OrderBy( m => m.Nombre));

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
    {
        var item = list[i];
        if (i == 0 && medico == null) medico = list[i];
        medicosList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Nombre + " " + item.Apellido, Value = item.Id.ToString()});
```

I need to mark somehow in the dropdownlist which "Medico" meets X condition. How can I achieve it?
I have a bool method to check the condition which can be called from controller, but after googling a lot I have no idea how to "mark" these.

Comment: First question to ask yourself: how would you do it in raw HTML?

Comment: Yes but how can I check in the controller itself this? I mean, I need to "pin" the ones I want beforehand. Right?

Comment: You didn't ask yourself that question, did you? Show me the HTML for a dropdown list with different colors.

Comment: Well, let me reprhase then. I need to make certain items of my @Html.DropDownListFor to have a different font/bg based on a condition. For this I have a bool method in my repository that will use Medico.Id and return the bool. This is just for presentation purposes, no logic required beyond that.

<select name="select">
  <option value="1" style="background-color: blue">Test</option>
  <option value="2" style="background-color: green">Test</option>
</select>

Comment: Excellent. Now note the answer from @Krilovich. You'll note a similarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't think of the top of my head how you could do it using a selectitem list and Html.DropDownList but you could easily do it in a different way

In your controller instead of what you have now simply only have the list because thats all you need

```
List<Medico> list = new List<Medico>(visitador.Medicos.OrderBy( m => m.Nombre));
** Edit **

foreach(var m in list)
{
  //check each one against your repository here and have something inside of Medico to tell you the result
}
```

and in your HTML you can easily create the dropdown list by yourself (**as long as the name properly is the same as the property name in your model which is Medico the binding will work**)

```
<select id="Medico" name="Medico">
 @foreach(var medico in (List<Medico>)ViewBag.Medicos)
 {
   if(medico.something = "something")
      <option id="@medico.Apellido" value="@medico.Id" style="background-color: blue">@medico.Nombre</option>
   else if(medico.something ="something else")
      <option id="@medico.Apellido" value="@medico.Id" style="background-color: red">@medico.Nombre</option>
 }
</select>
```

Basically in the foreach loop you can check each of your medico variables against a condition and depending on that you can give it a different class or style as you want

Comment: FYI, there's no sense in initializing to `null` if you're going to set the variable in the next statement.

Comment: Thanks for this , ill try it.
However the underlying problem still remains unless im not understanding properly. 
I cannot call my bool method in the repository from here, and what I need to compare is not an attribute of the medico entity.

Comment: Add a variable to your Medico class then and set it in your controller based on your repository method - a foreach loop should work

Comment: By the way as a better practice I suggest you look into using stongly binded views with view models instead of the ViewBag to pass variables

Answer (score 1):

combining code from here [remove specific items from dropdown list using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778237/remove-specific-items-from-dropdown-list-using-jquery) and here [Change the background color of dropdownlist JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103899/change-the-background-color-of-dropdownlist-jquery)

see if this will work for you

```
var $list = $("#myList"),
toColor= $();

for(var i = selectedItems.length; i--;) {
   toColor= toColor.add($list.find('option[value="' + selectedItems[i] + '"]'));
}
toColor.css(TextHighlightCss);
```